# Using Custom JS in SPFX (SharePoint Online Modern Sites)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have created a footer using custom js which fetches all the terms inside the termstore and displays it in the footer for the page and I have referenced the custom js and css files in the custom masterpage for SharePoint Online. This works well for classic pages. How can I use the js for creating the footer for modern pages using SPFX. I have created a basic footer using the link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

How can I enhance it to use the custom js to get terms from the termset and display it in the footer.

Comment: You are in the right direction. All you need to do is to modify and place your custom script to AppCustomizer.Ts file and then deploy your solution to SharePoint